# Jquery right click, no contextmenu, live and all browser

Tags: jquery, hover, live, right-click

i need i nice solution to manage the left-& rightclick on a div with a special class (live).
It is important for me that the code works on every new browser.

Hope somebody can help me.

My first try ... // the rightclick does not work

**HTML**

```
<div id="test_one" class="my_class">Click here</div>
<br /><br />
<div id="test_two" class="my_class">Click here</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function test()
{

    $(".my_class").bind("contextmenu",function(e){ return false; });

    $(".my_class").live('click', function(e)
    {
      if(e.button == 0 || e.button == 1)
      {
           alert('L -> '+this.id+'');
      }
      else if(e.button == 2){
           alert('R -> '+this.id+'');
      }
    });


});
```

**example:** http://jsfiddle.net/EWXse/

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-left-mouse-click-and-right-with-jquery

Comment: even this link contains the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007482/jquery-detect-if-middle-or-right-mouse-button-is-clicked-if-so-do-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of mousedown the right mouse lick is not detectable by default: http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/ .

[How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-left-mouse-click-and-right-with-jquery) suggests that you use event.which instead of event.button, as .which is normalised to 1,2,3 across all browsers.

For what it is worth: right mouse clicks don't seem to work in Google Chrome on Mac OS X here.

Comment: Maybe you need a second mouse button for that Mac? ;p

Comment: Actually, I have 5 buttons on the mouse here, and NONE of them apart from the first one appear in a simple alert(e.which)... :-)