# Stop anchor tag onclick function from executing for mouse scroll click

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser, anchor

I have an anchor tags like

```
<a href="#" onclick="Access('Product')">Product</a>
```

on clicking, it specify the jsp for an iframe 
I found mouse scroll click on the anchor tag loads the iframe in a seperate tab,so i want to disable 
the mouse scroll click.
I have tried [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392442/detect-middle-button-click-scroll-button-with-jquery)

```
$(function(){
    $('a').mouseup(function(e){         
        if (e.which === 2){
            alert();
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }        
    });
});
```

even then onclick function is triggered,
Any ideas?

Comment: You can unbind the mouseup event, ` $('a').unbind('mouseup');`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `href="javascript:void(0)"` in your anchor tag.

Comment: no luck.it opens an new tab without any content,i need to prevent it from opening new tab