# trigger two mouse events simultanious jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel, right-click

how can I trigger two mouse events simultanious (hold right clic and mouse weel) I have to press the right button of the mouse and hold on and at the same time I roll the wheel

```
    $("selector").bind("click mousewheel", (function(event, delta) {
           console.log("xxx")});
```

Comment: Seems like an awkward interaction, maybe there's a better combination using the keyboard. What is it for?

Comment: Very good question, I'm highly interested in knowing the answer -- I could apply the concept quite commonly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be not exactly you want but it works...

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DTNpC/)

```
var rightButtonDown = false;
$(document).mousedown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 3) rightButtonDown = true;
});
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 3) rightButtonDown = false;
});
$(document).mousewheel(function (event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    if (rightButtonDown) {
        console.log("fire!")
    }
});
```

Include [a jQuery plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) to handle the mousewheel event.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this demo** http://jsfiddle.net/HeDPZ/

Try event `mousedown` for any kind of click i.e. right or left.

*Behavior* - with the mouse `click` of when you `move wheel` you will see an alert poping.

Another thing is there is a small syntax error in your closing brackets.

For OP: Do you mind telling us bit more as to what kind of functioanlity you are aiming for just so that we can help you out in more detail.

**Captureing event like this** http://jsfiddle.net/dQWNY/ more here: [Detect middle button click (scroll button) with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392442/detect-middle-button-click-scroll-button-with-jquery)

- Left - 1
- Middle - 2
- Right - 3

I hope this is fits your need `:)`

**Code**

```
$(".vendor-icon").bind("mousedown mousewheel", function (event, delta) {
    alert("xxx");
});
```

**Associated html**

Comment: I think the OP is looking to detect when only both events are true "simultanious", not when either is true.

Comment: @j08691 Hiya bruv, I reckon this will work when both happens at same time `:)` coz of `mousedown` event. will treat any button down in mouse interface as mouse down.

Comment: @RUJordan Hiya man, I tried and it seemed to be working, Try pressing the missing Wheel of mouse with scrolling action and you will see the click `:))` although thius is very weird requirement :P

Comment: My apologies, my trackpad doesn't seem to function like a mouse (obvious reasons). Question: is there a way to make this trigger ONLY when both events happen?

Comment: @RUJordan No worries bro! Sure `:)` yes I reckon something like this `e.which` so capturing the target event and which key. **I guess** something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392442/detect-middle-button-click-scroll-button-with-jquery is conditional check `&&` should suffice, OP read this comment.

Comment: Would you mind showing a mini-example/a fiddle? (Or is it simply 2 if statements inside the trigger?). Either way, +1.

Comment: @RUJordan Saweet bruv, cheers for that! I will try and script small demo soon-ish `:)`