# How to handle middle mouse click?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an ember component that generates a list of groups of users. When a user clicks on one of the list components it calls a linkAction defined in the component and brings the user to the particular page associated with that list item. However when a user middle mouse clicks this component the user is then brought to /# by default and I cant figure out how to handle this behavior.

For reference here is the component as seen in the template.

```
    {{student-group-item linkAction='drillToGroup' drillId=teacherGroup.id
                group_name=teacherGroup.studentGroupName
                meta_class="quiz-item-meta"
                item_1_title= teacherGroup.numStudentsDisplay
                item_1_class="group-count"
                item_2_title=teacherGroup.createdDate
                item_2_class="created-on"
                item_3_title=teacherGroup.shortDescription
                item_3_class="group-desc"}}
```

and the drillToGroup action does the following

```
drillToGroup: function(id) {
  this.transitionTo('student-group',id);
},
```

How can I make this component respond to middle mouse click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer applies to Ember 2.x.x and was written as of version 2.15.

By default, closure events receive the event as an argument by default. For whatever reason, [mousedown will detect middle clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392442/detect-middle-button-click-scroll-button-with-jquery). Regular onclick does not.

In your template:

```
<button onmousedown={{action "clicked"}}>button</button>
```

In your component js:

```
actions: {
  clicked(event) {
    console.log(event.button)
    // do things based on button value of 0, 1, or 2. 1 is middle.
  }
}
```

You can read more about event handling in Ember in [The Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/components/handling-events/). The button attribute of a click event can be found in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click).

Be cautious when overriding middle and right clicks. It could lead to problematic UI for some use cases. There is no direct equivalent for touch/mobile, and many mice don't have wheels.