# How do I detect a "scroll click" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to detect a "scroll click", that is, when the user presses down the scroll wheel (that one between the left click and the right click in a mouse). Is there any way to do this in JavaScript, other than detecting the cursor type?

Comment: All [mouse events have a button property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button) on them telling you which button was pressed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392442/detect-middle-button-click-scroll-button-with-jquery