# Jquery alert when middle mouse button clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery: detect if middle or right mouse button is clicked, if so, do this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007482/jquery-detect-if-middle-or-right-mouse-button-is-clicked-if-so-do-this)

How do I show alert box that says "middle mouse button clicked" when I click on text, or any dom element? I want to be able to differentiate between middle mouse and normal right click using jquery/javscript.

I did refer to this:
[Jquery: detect if middle or right mouse button is clicked, if so, do this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007482/jquery-detect-if-middle-or-right-mouse-button-is-clicked-if-so-do-this)

and modified the js fiddle to this:
http://jsfiddle.net/zAGLP/29/

But am seeking an alternative to "live()" function.

Comment: You're asking how to do this without live, and on any text?  My answer should suffice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$(document).bind('mousedown', function(e) { 
   if( (e.which == 1) ) {
     alert("left button");
   }if( (e.which == 3) ) {
     alert("right button");
   }else if( (e.which == 2) ) {
      alert("middle button"); 
   }
   e.preventDefault();
}).bind('contextmenu', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
});
```