# Scroll div with "middle button" mouse instantly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I want to implement navigation in a website using the middle button function of scrolling (**"clicking"** (please re-read **clicking**) the middle button and roaming around the borders) but I would like this to happen instantly without the need for user input. Something of the kind:

```
 $(element).mouseover(function(){
            roamAround(); //I've tried SIMULATING (NOT <--- DETECTING)
                         //a middle-click from the mouse but failed
});
```

I am currently using google-chrome and at this stage of development I **am not really concerned about cross-browsing this function.** If it should work on chrome then it's fine.
What would be the best way to do this using native functions or emulation? Thank you very much!

EDIT:  **I don't want to DETECT user input, please re-read the question :)**

Comment: Please refer to this, this answers your question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833928/jquery-alert-when-middle-mouse-button-clicked

Comment: has nothing to do with my question xD re-read my question please

Comment: This is how you would detect a middle click: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4007656/2827555

Comment: What he wants is Google Maps but without clicking.  He just wants the gesture of moving the mouse - essentially an infinite scroller

Comment: This is the best one I can find so far, most of the ones provided pre-made are for WordPress for some reason lol http://jscroll.com/ - you'll have to probably duplicate the objects so you can capture vertical AND horizontal gesturing.  I love the idea though hope I see the final product in the wild some day

Comment: @Deryck thank you for trying Deryck! What I am really aiming for is something of this kind http://scripterlative.com/files/dragscroll.htm but without the need to press and drag, just drag the mouse around :p I guess I'll have to develop my own, thank you very much again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want, like [Deryck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2780033/deryck) said, infinite scrolling. There's a jQuery plugin [jScroll](http://jscroll.com/) that does a simpler version for vertical content that can either be auto-loaded or loaded by a button press. You can view the code on [Github](https://github.com/pklauzinski/jscroll/blob/master/jquery.jscroll.js) to see how to do something similar, i.e. your `roamAround` function could mimic the `_load` function found there.