# Either do a function or open a new tab with Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, tabs

I'm working on a page which works fine for now, but I'd like to make it a bit more responsive by using ajax.
So I want to call a JS function and staying on the page when left clicking on a link, but when clicking with the middle mouse button (for opening a new tab) I don't want to execute the function but instead open a new tab (like a regular link).

Right now I have something like this:

```
<a href="someSite.php" id="myLink">Link</a>
```

and

```
myLink.onclick = function () {
  doAjax();
  return false;
};
```

But in this case clicking with the middle mouse button calls the function.

Is there a way without using any button detection and no jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect middle mouse button click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224327/how-to-detect-middle-mouse-button-click)

Comment: You will need to check the button. There is no "middle" click event.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use some jquery,

```
$("#myLink").on("mousedown", "a.external", function(e) {
        if( (e.which == 1) ) {
                //left click make your ajax call
        }else if( (e.which == 2) ) {
                //middle click open your new tab
                var _window = window.open('your link', '_blank');
                if(_window){
                        _window.focus();
                }else{
                        console.log('popup blocked');
                }
        }
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: live is not valid jQuery. It was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in version 1.9. And the OP said not with jQuery.

Comment: @epascarello the OP said **or** jQuery, anyway one does not *have to* use jquery for this.

Comment: Sorry, without jQuery would be nice.

Comment: Yes, I don't need a lot of JS, so loading jQuery would be overkill. ;)