# How can I emulate a middle button mouse click in selenium with javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium

I want to emulate a middle button mouse click on a text URL on a page so it will open on a new tab, in Selenium coding in JavaScript.

For example:

```
await driver.get("https://google.com");

//thats the xpath for the 'terms' text url
await driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/a[2]')).click();
```

Comment: that should click on `terms`, what is your expected outcome  ?

Comment: My expected outcome is to click on terms as 'middle button mouse click' so it opens the terms in a new tab

Comment: is it liking clicking when ctrl is pressed ?

Comment: Yes, exactly as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution

I can just send 2 keys on the element which is ctrl & enter

```
 await driver.get("https://google.com");
 //thats the xpath for the 'terms' text URL
 await driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/a[2]')).sendKeys(Key.CONTROL, Key.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is some code that is not direct solution but might lead you to real solution look
([How to detect middle mouse button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224327/how-to-detect-middle-mouse-button-click/21224428))[here]