# Do something in hover if the right button of the mouse is down (pressed)

Tags: jquery, hover, mouse

I need to zoom an image when mouse is over the image and the right button of the mouse is kept pressed. something like:

```
$('img').hover(
     function(){
       if (the-right-mouse-button-is-pressed){
         $(this).animate({
         width:  $(this).width() *2,
         height: $(this).height()*2,
         }, 500);
       }
     },
});
```

I need help. Thanks.

Comment: A lil' bit of search.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706655/bind-event-to-right-mouse-click, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007482/jquery-detect-if-middle-or-right-mouse-button-is-clicked-if-so-do-this

Comment: I saw that. It is different from my question. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** For your below comment,

> Thanks. However, it requires a right-click on the picture. it does not
>   work if you keep the right button down somewhere else in the screen
>   and then pass the image

You need to add mouseup event and zoom conditionally. See below code, [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PhM8P/3/)

```
var hasExpanded = false;
$('img').on('mousedown mouseup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 3) {
            if (!hasExpanded) {
            $(this).animate({
                width: $(this).width() * 2,
                height: $(this).height() * 2,
            }, 500);
        }
        hasExpanded = true;
    }
}).mouseleave(function(e) {
    if (hasExpanded  == true) {
    $(this).animate({
        width: $(this).width() / 2,
        height: $(this).height() / 2,
    }, 500);
    hasExpanded = false;
}
});
```

---

What you need cannot be achieved through hover. Hover will be triggered on `mouseeneter` which will be called only once and It cannot record the `mousedown` event which happens at later point.

You need to implement `mousedown` handler. See below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/PhM8P/2/) - Demo has both `mousedown` and `mouseleave` implemented.

```
$('img').mousedown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 3) {
        $(this).animate({
            width: $(this).width() * 2,
            height: $(this).height() * 2,
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. However, it requires a right-click on the picture. it does not work if you keep the right button down somewhere else in the screen and then pass the image.

Comment: @BaharS Updated code handling the mouseup case on the image. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PhM8P/3/).