# Middle mouse click event in jquery

Tags: jquery, fancybox, mouseevent, mousewheel

I want control middle mouse button, I mean when user left clicked of middle clicked or right clicked on my link I should show fancybox.

so I use this code :

```
$(".reg").live("mousedown", function(e) {
    if ((e.which == 1) || (e.which == 2) || (e.which == 3)) {
        $.fancybox({
            href : 'register.php'
        });
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

But on this code just left click will work.

Comment: Apart from your question...now you should use `.on` rather than `.live`

Comment: @Peeyush Thanks but no difference in result

Comment: that's why i said...apart from your question.it is just a best practice.

Comment: Any specific browser?

Comment: `if ((e.which == 1) || (e.which == 2) || (e.which == 3))` Why are you using a conditional that will always be true? ps. Your code should work fine.

Comment: There is not a real cross-browser solution, you cannot prevent default action of middle button in Firefox for instance. Some useful links : http://unixpapa.com/js/testmouse.html and http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html

Answer (score -1):

Please try the solution written here http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4007482/jquery-detect-if-middle-or-right-mouse-button-is-clicked-if-so-do-this

May be it work for you.

example:

```
$(".reg").on('mousedown', function(e) { 
   if( (e.which == 1) ) {
     alert("left button");
   } else if( (e.which == 3) ) {
     alert("right button");
   } else if( (e.which == 2) ) {
      alert("middle button"); 
   }
   e.preventDefault();
}).on('contextmenu', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p49nF/ . I tested it in Firefox 19 & Chrome 25 and it is working fine for me.

Comment: Please refer to an existing answer as a comment rather than just copy/past from it and/or link to it