# Handling clicks on links myself - JQuery Mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, click, mousedown

I want to handle clicks on specific  elements myself.
So that if I click it with the left mousebutton it opens the link in the current tab and if I click it with the middlebutton, it opens it in a new tab.
I want to do this by getting the href attribute from the link and use window.open()

Is this even possible without running into popupblocker issues?

So for starters I tried to prevent the opening of the link.

HTML:

```
<a href="somelink.php" class="prev_cl"><img src="someimg.png" /></a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('.prev_cl').on('mousedown', function(e){
        return false;
    });
})
```

But even this isn't working, it still opens the link.
If I put an alert before "return false" it actually doesn't trigger the click and shows the alertbox. But who wants an alert box everytime they click a link?

I also tried using both mouseup and mousedown events, but that didn't work either

Another thing I tried was putting the return false to the element itself, meaning:

```
 <a href="somelink.php" onclick="return false" class="prev_cl"><img src="someimg.png" /></a>
```

Then on the javascript part I added window.open() to it

But 1) clicking with middlemousebutton still works and 2) Firefox blocks the opening of the window because it thinks it is a popup

Answer (score 0):

Put your handler on the `click` event, not `mousedown`.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.prev_cl').on({
        'click': function(e){
           if (e.which == 1) {
                var button = "left";
            } else {
                button = "middle";
            }
            console.log(button+" click");
            console.log(e.which);
            e.preventDefault();
        },
        'contextmenu': function(e) {
            console.log("right click");
            console.log(e.which);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="somelink.php" class="prev_cl"><img src="someimg.png" /></a>
```

Comment: Even if this would work, I need to distinguish(or it would be nice to) between left click and middleclick. Afaik this is not possible with 'click' or am I wrong?

Comment: You can use the `contextmenu` event to handle right click. I'm still working on the middle button.

Comment: I don't have a mouse with a middle button, so I'm not sure if my answer really works. It might be necessary to use `mousedown` to catch the middle button if `click` doesn't trigger for it. It should just check for `e.which == 2` for that case.

Comment: well thats my initial problem, that return false or preventdefault() on mousedown is not working

Comment: When you click on something, multiple events are triggered: `mousedown` and `mouseup` for any click, `click` for left-click, `contextmenu` for right-click, I'm not sure what for middle-click. Following the link or displaying the menu comes from the `click` and `contextmenu` events, so you need to handle those events and prevent their defaults to override.

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault()` of jQuery can be used to **prevent the default action of an event**, in this case **the click**.

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault

Also, you can catch middle (or any) mouse button like this: [Jquery: detect if middle or right mouse button is clicked, if so, do this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007482/jquery-detect-if-middle-or-right-mouse-button-is-clicked-if-so-do-this)

Comment: not working, I put it on both mousedown and mouseup and tried 'click' too

Comment: `return false` does the same thing as calling `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: I know how to detect the middle click in the mousedown, but I still need to prevent the default action, thats my main problem right now

Comment: @Harshadewa still fires when using the middle button

Comment: No it does not. I added 2 links now; one with preventDefault and one without. http://jsfiddle.net/w16a33kq/1/